# why inforation payment tap is disable for payment plugin in nopcommerce store

Tags: nopcommerce

I am try to devlope payment method plugin for nopcommerce 4.30 it work good and install on store from admin area but when chose my payment method from checkout bage the information payment tab disable as show in picture
[disable for payment plugin in nopcommerce store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO80Z.png)

how can enable this tab

Comment: did you inherited your Plugins processor class with `IPaymentMethod` Interface.

Answer (score 1):

Because there are no available active payment methods. Just install/enable COD payment method or CheckMoneyOrder